# Android: Transform Checkbox objects into an Array to which apply a set of rules

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, checkbox

I am new to coding, so I am not entirely sure what I am about to ask will make sense. Please let me know if it doesn't.

I am developing a quiz in android, and I have created four Checkbox objects in my java file. To each Checkbox object will apply a set of rules. The rules to be applied are all the same. Here is my code:

```
byte numberOfCheckedBoxesQ2 = 0;
boolean hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A1, hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A2, hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A3, hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A4;
CheckBox Q2A1, Q2A2, Q2A3, Q2A4;
```

[...]

method:

```
    Q2A1 = findViewById(R.id.Q2A1);
    hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A1 = Q2A1.isChecked();
    if (hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A1) {numberOfCheckedBoxesQ2 +=1;}

    Q2A2 = findViewById(R.id.Q2A2);
    hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A2 = Q2A2.isChecked();
    if (hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A2) {numberOfCheckedBoxesQ2 +=1;}

    Q2A3 = findViewById(R.id.Q2A3);
    hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A3 = Q2A3.isChecked();
    if (hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A3) {numberOfCheckedBoxesQ2 +=1;}

    Q2A4 = findViewById(R.id.Q2A4);
    hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A4 = Q2A4.isChecked();
    if (hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A4) {numberOfCheckedBoxesQ2 +=1;}

    if (numberOfCheckedBoxesQ2 > 2) {...}
```

Because I am using the same rules with the same object types, would employing an array not make this process much more straightforward and elegant? And if it would, how exactly would I do that?

Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: are the checkboxes objects  the ones with the right answers?

Comment: some are, and some are not.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android development, but can you use lambdas? `Stream.of(true, false, true, true).mapToInt(v -> v ? 1 : 0).sum()` this, for example would give you 3 as an answer, which you're seemingly doing (summing boolean variables, and counting one for each that's true). It's probably cleaner to prepare a list of checkboxes or their 'checked' values separately, too, so you might indeed create an array, or better yet use Java's List like ArrayList.

Comment: I don't understand ur code but I can see that you can do it with arrays 
create an array of Integers for ids of checkboxes `int[] ids = {R.id.Q2A1, ....... }`
and iterate over them.

Comment: @ David Ibrahim
@ pafau k.

Thanks, everyone! This might just be what I've been looking for. 
I'll try both, see what it looks like, and then leave an update. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves my question:

```
byte i, numberOfCheckedBoxesQ2 = 0;
final byte NUMBER_OF_CHECKBOXES_FOR_Q2 = 4;
int[] idsQ2A = {R.id.Q2A1, R.id.Q2A2, R.id.Q2A3, R.id.Q2A4};
boolean[] hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_CHECKBOXES_FOR_Q2];
CheckBox[] Q2A = new CheckBox[NUMBER_OF_CHECKBOXES_FOR_Q2];
```

[...]

method:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHECKBOXES_FOR_Q2; i++) {
        Q2A[i] = findViewById(idsQ2A[i]);
        hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A[i] = Q2A[i].isChecked();
        if (hasCorrectAnswerForQ2A[i]) {numberOfCheckedBoxesQ2 += 1;}
    }
```

I haven't tried lambdas yet, but I will have a look at those in a bit. 
Thanks again! @ David Ibrahim @ pafau k.